# VBScript Issue Help Required

Tags: vbscript

I need a script that can run and pull information from any drive on a Windows operating system (Windows Server 2003), listing all files and folders which contain the following fields: The server is quite big and is within our domain.

The required information is:

- Full file path (e.g. C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\testPage.doc)
- File type (e.g. word document, spreadsheet, database etc)
- Size
- When Created
- When last modified
- When last accessed

Also the script will need to convert that data to a CSV file, which later on I can modify and process in Excel. I can imagine that this data will be huge but I still need it. I am logged in as an administrator on the server and the script will need to also process protected files. As in previous posts I have read that the script will stop if such files are processed. I need to make sure that not a single file is skipped.

***Please note I have asked this question before but still have not got a working script.***

### This is the script I got so far, file Test.vbs:

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo Chr(34) & "Full Path" &_
 Chr(34) & ","  & Chr(34) & "File Size" &_
 Chr(34) & ","  & Chr(34) & "File Date modified" &_
 Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "File Date Created" &_
 Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "File Date Accessed" & Chr(34)
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFolder = objArgs(0)
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
Go (objFolder)
Sub Go(objDIR)
  If objDIR <> "\System Volume Information" Then
    For Each eFolder in objDIR.SubFolders
        Go eFolder
    Next
  End If
    For Each strFile In objDIR.Files
        WScript.Echo Chr(34) & strFile.Path & Chr(34) & "," &_
        Chr(34) & strFile.Size & Chr(34) & "," &_
        Chr(34) & strFile.DateLastModified & Chr(34) & "," &_
        Chr(34) & strFile.DateCreated & Chr(34) & "," &_
        Chr(34) & strFile.DateLastAccessed & Chr(34)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

I am currently using the command-line to run it:

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo Test.vbs "c:\" > "C:\test\Output.csv"
```

The script is not working. I don't know why.

Comment: does it give any error messages?

Comment: it generates the CSV file and looks like something launches but nothing happens, thats it really, its not running though.

Comment: This question will most likely be closed as a duplicate of your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272317/vbs-script-help.  The only suggestion I could give you is to try and make sure the appropriate tags are set on your question and, try and earn some more rep so that you can offer a bounty.  Bounty questions generate more interest because there are higher reputation rewards for answering them.

Comment: how can you close it if its not answered, I see that the activity of each question is only 30mins to 1 hour, and also understand the point system, but the whole point of this website is to ask questions and get answers right? then what is more important to help someone or to just get a few points.

I let you decide, if you want to close it go ahead, if not Thank You

Comment: I am interested in this issue/bug. Would you be so kind enough as to post/upload here [1]The file it generates & [2]The Output on the command-line...

Comment: Also, did you try hard-coding the file/directory path. Does it work properly then??

Answer (score 0):

### Properly passing cmd-line args to vbs when using Cscript

---

-Modify the cmd-line statement as follows (drop the ">")

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo Test.vbs "c:\" "C:\test\Output.csv"
```

-Next inside the script you can access the cmd-line parameters as follows

```
strFolder = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
strFile = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

I hope now you can access the files and list them properly in the csv-file. :-)

GoodLUCK!!
- CVS