# Permission Denied when running VBScript

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, export

I have a vbs script which captures file information and then exports it to a csv file. I need to run the script on main drives such as C:\, E:\, I:\ and more, but each time I run for the main directory I get "Permission Denied" when I try to run it for a subfolder example C:\Program Files it works fine. I have tested this on different desktop machines and servers with full admin accounts and still get it.

What could be the issue with this code. test.vbs

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFS, objFld
Dim objArgs
Dim strFolder, strDestFile, blnRecursiveSearch
Dim strLines()
Dim i
Dim strCsv

    i = 0

'   'Get the commandline parameters
'   Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments 
'   strFolder = objArgs(0)
'   strDestFile = objArgs(1)
'   blnRecursiveSearch = objArgs(2)

    '###################################
    'MAKE SURE THESE VALUES ARE CORRECT
    '###################################
    strFolder = "C:\" 
    strDestFile = "C:\Output.csv" 
    blnRecursiveSearch = True

    'Create the FileSystemObject
    Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get the directory you are working in 
    Set objFld = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)

    'Now get the file details
    GetFileDetails objFld, blnRecursiveSearch 

    'Write the csv file
    Set strCsv = objFS.CreateTextFile(strDestFile, True)
    strCsv.Write Join(strLines, vbCrLf)

    'Close and cleanup objects
    strCsv.Close
    Set strCsv = Nothing
    Set objFld = Nothing
    Set strFolder = Nothing
    Set objArgs = Nothing


Private Sub GetFileDetails(fold, blnRecursive)
Dim fld, fil
dim strLine(5)

    If blnRecursive Then
        'Work through all the folders and subfolders
        For Each fld In fold.SubFolders
            GetFileDetails fld, True 
        Next
    End If

    'Now work on the files
    For Each fil in fold.Files
        strLine(0) = fil.Path
        strLine(1) = fil.Type
        strLine(2) = fil.Size
        strLine(3) = fil.DateCreated
        strLine(4) = fil.DateLastModified
        strLine(5) = fil.DateLastAccessed

        Redim Preserve strLines(i)
        strLines(i) = Join(strLine, ",")
        i = i + 1
    Next
end sub
```

Please advise and modify code if you know where the issue is.

Comment: what command are you using to run the file?

Comment: cscript.exe C:\temp\script\test.vbs

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279705/vbscript-issue-help-required  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272317/vbs-script-help

Answer (score 0):

If it's a permissions problem I would strongly recommend [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals to diagnose it.  You should be able to watch the cscript process (or whatever is executing your script) and find out what kind of permission problem you're having.

Comment: i dont get this issue with any other script thought, and cannot see where the problem is on the code. I think becuase it only specifies to search folders and not main drive directory. The error seems to lie in Line 50, 3.

Comment: C:\script\test.vbs(50, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied